# Variable declared on the previous line does not seem to exist

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a new "MySqlConnection" object, but the following gives the IDE 1007 error, "The name "con" does not exist in the current context.":

```
MySqlConnection con;
con = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1; database=prueba3; Uid=root; pad=root;");
```

The following gives CS0102, "The "Game" type already contains a definition for "con".":

```
MySqlConnection con;
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1; database=miprueba; Uid=root; pad=root;");
```

Finally, this gives the original error, ""con" does not exist in the current context":

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1; database=miprueba; Uid=root; pad=root;");
con.Open();
```

How to fix this?

Edit 1 (code before the lines that give the error):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using Pokemon;

using System.Linq;
using MySql.Data;
using MySqlConnector;

namespace Pokemon
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Game
    // Class of the game.
    {
        IO io;                                      // New object of the "IO" class.
        bool quickstart = true;
        bool graphical = false;
        bool release = false;
        string savePath = @"../../../ProTEST5.txt"; // Path of the save file.
```

Comment: Does it happen with a different variable name? Just curious.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Tried "con1", same errors.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the full method/code? Further side note: your connection string is wrong: 'pad' is not a valid parameter name for MySql conn-strings. Quite sure you actually meant 'pwd'..

Comment: @SanchoPanza The code before it is just what is on the first edit

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than bits and pieces. Without a complete, minimal example it's *really* hard to know what's going on.

Comment: Note that the context really matters - you can't use `con = new MySqlConnection(...)` as a statement *in a class declaration*... it would have to be in a constructor, or a method. (I strongly suspect that absolutely none of the problems you're facing are related to MySQL, btw... I think this is just core C#.)

Comment: You need to put code into a function, not straight into the class definition. And don't cache connection objects, create when needed and dispose with a `using`

Comment: I didn't notice it was directly in the class, putting it in a function fixed the problem. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

try using something like:

```
public void ExampleMethod(){
    MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "database=myDB;server=localhost;user id=myUser; pwd=myPass";
    myConnection.Open();
    (...)
}
```

also make sure your connection string is okay, I'm not sure about your "pad=root;" in your connection string

Comment: Same error, on the second line it says the "myConnection" name does not exist in the current context

Comment: After seeing your edit posting the code before your call, noticed that your MySqlConnection call isn't inside a method, put it inside a method and the error should be solved

Comment: What's the point of opening a connection only to abandon it? You need to open a connection when necessary and dispose with `using`.

Comment: That you must ask the OP, was just providing an example method where he could put his code in a way that it wouldn't break

Comment: @Charlieface Keeping the call to the "Open()" function was only for illustrative purposes to show that the error appeared right after as well. My mistake was not putting the code in a method, as jsilva said.

Comment: You still need a `using` though, also you can shorten it by putting the connection string in the constructor